# Joomla Related Product Customizartion

Tags: joomla2.5

In VM2, I can use the template override default_relatedproducts.php
with the following code:

```
 <?php echo $field->display ?>

That outputs the HTML

<a title="x" href="x">
   <img alt="" src="x.jpg"> 
   Product Name 
</a>
```

My question is how to remove the Product Name in the above href codemi just want image

Comment: i have tried this code but nothing happens

Comment: <?php
    $image_dir = JURI::root()."images/";

    foreach($this->product->customfieldsRelatedProducts as $field) {
        echo $field->display; 
        ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image_dir.$field->image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $field->title ?>" />
        <?php
    }
?>